# randomly splice values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array "A" of scrambled, randomly generated ASCII characters... and a message "M". I want to insert the characters of message M into array A such that the order of M's characters are intact... but randomly distributed throughout array A.

Original array: zH$@%@$#@$@^^#@(%*$@^&@!$^%&

Sample output: zH$@%@^**t**$#@$@^^**h**#@(%*$@^&@**i**!$^%&**s**, etc...

```
                    var randomChars = [];
                    for(var i=33;i<127;++i) {
                        var letter = document.createElement('span');
                        letter.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(i);
                        randomChars.push(letter);
                    }

                    var message = "this is a message";
                    var rand = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < message.split("").length; i++) {    
                        rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * randomChars.length) + rand);
                        var letters = document.createElement('span');
                        letters.innerHTML = message.split("")[i];
                        letters.setAttribute("hidden","");
                        randomChars.splice(rand, 0, letters); 
                    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ftm2srz/1/

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "order of the message is maintained". Once you scramble the letters in the array, what's next ?

Comment: what do you mean by randomly scatter mantaining the order of the message? It doesn't make much sense like this.

Comment: You have to post example of the source data and the result.

Comment: Where is the message string in the given sample?

Comment: An attempt to re-state your problem : you have an array "A" of characters, and a message M. You want to scramble M's chars and insert them, randomly, into A. Is this it ?

Comment: Seems so veverke growler, Your random should not start from 0 your random should start from the last position you've entered the last letter

Comment: @Veverke Backwards. I have an array "A" of scrambled, randomly generated ASCII characters... and a message "M"... I want to insert the characters of message M into array A such that the order of message M's characters are intact... but randomly distributed throughout array A

Comment: @hindmost it's there in variable "message"

Comment: also growler change `[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("span[hidden]")`  to `Array.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("span[hidden]")` its faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the previous random index as the minimum (non inclusive) of your next randomly generated index. Start at zero.

You could end up with some barely scrambled stuff, though. (!@#!$!@$#!@#this) But it's random.

**EDIT** A better way would be to generate a `message.length` amount of unique random indices, sort them in ascending, and then insert characters from `message` at those spots in the scrambled array.

http://jsbin.com/kuzepujabo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I had thought about this before too... I'm wondering why the letters are all clumping up at the end- the randomly generated numbers are beyond the length of the array

Comment: That would be randomly selected and in order, though. If the first letter of your message gets placed near the end of the array then all the rest of the letters must come after, and so you get the "clump". Does it have to be random? You could make a seemingly random looking distribution by dividing your target array into a section for each letter to place, then randomly placing a letter in each section, and recombining. It's not really random, but there's some randomness to it. You would also have a somewhat even distribution.

Comment: "Random" and "in order" are contradictory, so to have things in order you're going to sacrifice 'randomness' to some degree.

Comment: "Random" and "in order" are contradictory if referring to the same thing. But in this case, Random refers to the index at which a letter of the message M is inserted into array A, and In Order refers to the preserving the index order of each letter in message M such that... if a letter x in message M has index 0, and a letter y in message M has index 1, x will always be inserted into array A before y.

Comment: They are still related. The index in which you insert your letters from M must be partially determined from where the previous letters were placed. Your example illustrates that.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to do with concat, or some sort of javascript merge?

Comment: See jsbin in original answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71814/discussion-between-growler-and-fozzle).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var o = {
   array: "zH$@%@$#@$@^^#@(%*$@^&@!$^%&".split(''),
   msg: "this is a message",
   randomMsgIndex: function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.msg.length); },
   randomMsgChar: function () { return this.msg[this.randomMsgIndex()]; },
   //resultingArray: [],
   randomArrayIndex: function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array.length); }
}

for(var i = 0; i < o.msg.length; i++) {
  o.array.splice(o.randomArrayIndex(), 0, o.randomMsgChar());
}

console.log(o.array);
```

I have come up with this - but I assume it is still not what you want - you probably want something that keeps track of which message chars were already added - so not to add them twice - and make sure the entire message (all its characters) were added to the array.

**Version 2** with the *feature* described above:

```js
var o = {
   array: "zH$@%@$#@$@^^#@(%*$@^&@!$^%&".split(''),
   msg: "this is a message",
   msgArray: function () { this.msg.split(''); },
   randomMsgIndex: function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.msg.length); },
   randomMsgChar: function (i) { return this.msg[i]; },
   //resultingArray: [],
   randomArrayIndex: function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array.length); },
   stripStr: function (indexToSkip, originalStr) { 
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < originalStr.length; i++)
     if (indexToSkip != i)
      result += originalStr[i];

    return result;
   }
}


for(var i = 0; i < o.msg.length; i++) {
  var msgRandomIndex = o.randomMsgIndex();
  o.array.splice(o.randomArrayIndex(), 0, o.randomMsgChar(msgRandomIndex));
  o.msg = o.stripStr(msgRandomIndex, o.msg);
}

console.log(o.array);
```

I think it it is still not a 100%, but moving towards the "optimized" solution :-)